# I am new to react and I'm following this tutorial on freecodecamp. I'm stuck on to do list, but my code is same as in the tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I'm following this tutorial on freecodecamp. I'm stuck on to do list, but my code is same as in the tutorial.

I get this errors: !Error: Unknown error (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237)

!The above error occurred in the  component: in TodoItem (created by App) in div (created by App) in App Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:248)

Here is my code, I'm working on scrimba.
Sorry if my english is bad.

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import todosData from "./todosData"

function App() {
    const todoItems = todosData.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item}/>)
    return (
        <div className="CBoxes">
         {todoItems}
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

```
import React from "react"

function TodoItem() {
    <div className ="CBoxItem">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <p>{props.item.text}</p>
    </div>
}

export default TodoItem
```

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
const todosData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery-shopping",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Clean gecko tank",
        completed: false 
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Mow lawn",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id:5, 
        text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
        completed: false
    }
]
export default todosData
```

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import App from "./App"

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke ;
 }
   
 .CBoxes{
     background-color: white;
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     border: 1px solid #efefef;
     box-shadow:
        0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
        0 10px 0 -5px #eee,
        0 10px 1px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
        0 20px 0 -10px #eee,
        0 20px 1px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 30px;
 }
 
 .CBoxItem{
     align-items: center;
     padding: 30px 20px 0;
     width: 70%;
     border-bottom: 70%;
     font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: #333333;
 }
 
input[type=checkbox]:focus {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.pack.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: What are you using to pack your JS code into  `index.pack.js`?

Comment: You need to pass the props as argument to the functional component `function TodoItem(props) {`

Comment: Ian I dont know im new to React and I'm using scrimba online, in scrimba you can write code without any setup

Comment: I passed it in and it still not working. I get this error messages. !Error: Unknown error (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237) Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:248) /index.html  -@RajdeepDebnath

Comment: Please remove `import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"` from todosData. and also why you name it like index.pack.js, `<script src="index.pack.js"></script>`. I guess it should be `<script src="index.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you i found solution... My todoItem function didnt have return()... Thanks for help :))  @RajdeepDebna and Ian